# How to remove spaces only before the First letter

Tags: notepad++

How to remove spaces only before the First letter and do not change to other words / text in line.

[image]

Comment: Please, instead of an image, post the text.

Comment: `Shift+Tab`...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^\h+`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           # beginning of line
  \h+       # 1 or more horizontal spaces
```

Answer (score 0):

Notepad++

Just press ALT while at the same time select with the mouse the first column. This is called "column mode". When done, just press delete to delete the first column just selected.

You can also use: ALT + SHITF + Arrow Key to select the black chars in the first column.